# use of 'all' with a possessive adjective

Tags: possessives, determiners

What is the right way to use the determiner 'all' with a possessive adjective e.g. my, your, etc? What is placed first? all or P. Adj?

A.  His **all** habits were unique.

B. **All** his habits were unique.

Is A wrong?

Answer (score 1):

"all" is always before adjectives. "all" even goes before articles, for example: "all the bad habits"

Comment: *All*, possessive pronouns, and articles are *determiners*.  A noun can have one and only one determiner--but *all* is also a "pre-determiner" so it's able to exist with the article.